# Get results from mysql table for specific month, php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get results from mysql table for specific month. I write query but query not working properly. Can someone help ?

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(size) as size FROM tb_size WHERE MONTH(date_created) = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, "Oct") . "' AND YEAR(date_created) =   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
$size = $result->size;
echo $size;
```

Comment: You should seriously consider using prepared statements.  Had you done that, it might have fixed the error, or at the very least made it much easier to see what the source of the error is.

Comment: "not working properly" is not a proper problem statement. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

`MONTH()` returns a number.  So your query should like like this:

```
SELECT sum(size) as size
FROM tb_size
WHERE MONTH(date_created) = 10 AND YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE();
```

If you want `Oct` to match, you can use `DATE_FORMAT()` instead:

```
SELECT sum(size) as size
FROM tb_size
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%b') = 'Oct' AND YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: @Tanya Instead of just saying "working great" and "thanks", use the checkmark and upvote buttons. It's what they're there for ;)

Answer (score 0):

as stated - `Month` returns a number: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php

you could use `MonthName`: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php but that returns a full name (October) and not Oct like you're using.

you could also use `DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%b')`to get the short month name

Comment: Why would you reference a secondary site such as "w3resource" rather than the actual product documentation?  This is all properly documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Comment: I find it to be a quicker read, more then enough for the purpose at hand.